# Mobile phone plug and play via USB

Tags: android, mobile

Is there a mobile phone which doesn't require any configuration steps to connect it to the PC?

I want to quickly send files (music) to it and be done, no additional software or drivers like itunes or whatever.

Also it should be easy to connect to a wlan with it, and by easy i mean also no 4 menus i have to click through.

So which mobile phones have these 2 features?

Or should I just use cardreaders for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont want any software so how can you transfer file without them.
if you are using android phone then you can use **shareit** for phone and pc and you have to establish connection for transfer the data.i am using **shareit** and it is best for transfer files.

Comment: hi, i meant, i plug the phone via a usb-cable on my pc and just see the phone as a drive, like with any normal usb-stick. If that works with shareit then thanks :)

Comment: not like drive but in shareit you will find your all data,so you can transfer your data whenever you want.but the problem is you have to download shareit for both pc and mobile.

Comment: i'm ok with that, seems still easier then my latest experience with HUAWEI, where i installed a software(from manufacturer) and it didnt work.